# Stabilizer Code with small support

Tags: error-correction

The support of an $ n $ qubit state is the number of nonzero coefficients when the state is written as a linear combination of computational basis kets.

The Steane $ [[7,1,3]] $ code has logical 0 and logical 1 which are both a uniform superposition over 8 computational basis kets.
\begin{align}
|0>_L=& |0000000>+|1010101>+|0110011>+|1100110>\\
&+|0001111>+|1011010>+|0111100>+|1101001>\\
|1>_L=& |1111111>+|0101010>+|1001100>+|0011001>\\
&+|1110000>+|0100101>+|1000011>+|0010110>
\end{align}
Support 8 is very small. What are examples of other quantum error correcting $ [[n,1,3]] $ codes with even smaller support? For example support $ 1 $ or $ 2 $ or $ 4 $?

Comment: For CSS codes I think the number of terms should be just $2^{|H_x|}$. This is the order of the group generated by $H_x$ taken as a classical code. The $[[9,1,3]]$ code can have either $|H_x|=2, |H_z|=6$ or  $|H_x|=6, |H_z|=2$. The first version would give you four terms. Relationship of $|H_x|$ to distance may not be straight forward.

Answer (score 3):

Let's think for a moment why the Steane code basis state have a support of 8. The Steane code is a CSS code with generators,
$$g_0 = X_0X_1X_2X_3$$
$$g_1 = X_0X_1X_4X_5$$
$$g_2 = X_0X_2X_4X_6$$
$$g_3 = Z_0Z_1Z_2Z_3$$
$$g_4 = Z_0Z_1Z_4Z_5$$
$$g_5 = Z_0Z_2Z_4Z_6$$

The zero-basis state is constructed via
$$|\bar 0\rangle = (I+g_0)\cdots (I+g_5)|0000000\rangle.$$
But the generators $g_3,g_4,g_5$ are $Z$ type generators and don't do anything to $|0000000\rangle$. So we are left with
$$|\bar 0\rangle = (I+g_0)(I+g_1)(I+g_3)|0000000\rangle.$$

You can see that this state must have a support of 8 because there are 8 unique combinations of $g_0,g_1,g_2$ multiplying $|0000000\rangle$.

You can easily see that this result is general. For a CSS code, if there are $r_x$ $X$-type generators, then the support of the encoded basis states will be $2^{r_x}$.

The next natural question to ask ourselves is, can we somehow reduce the number of $X$-type generators? Or concretely, for a $[[n,k=1,d=3]]$ code, how small can we make $r_x$?

Let's look at the Steane code again in terms of its error-correcting properties. The Steane code corrects any single-qubit bit-flip or phase-flip error. What are the possible phase-flip errors (which are corrected by $X$-type generators)? They are eight such errors: $\{I, Z_0,\dots, Z_6\}$, where the $I$ is no error. So, to distinguish between these 8 possibilities, we need 3 bits of information, which is provided by having 3 $X$-type generators in our code. If we have any fewer, then the code will not be able to identify every phase-flip error.

This result is *valid for any non-degenerate codes*. If there are $n$ physical qubits, then there will be $n+1$ possible single-qubit phase-flip errors (including the identity). To identify each one, we will need at least $\log_2(n+1)$ $X$-type generators, i.e. $r_x \ge \log_2(n+1)$. *If the code is degenerate, then fewer $X$-type generators will be required*.

From our first result, we can immediately see that the support of the encoded basis states will have to be at least $n+1$.

I will leave it to you to think about if and how the results change if $k \ne 1$ or $d \ne 3$.

Comment: Does this result that an $ [[n,1,3]] $ code must have support at least $ n+1 $ hold for just $ [[n,1,3]] $ CSS codes? All $ [[n,1,3]] $ stabilizer codes? All $ [[n,1,3]] $ codes?

Comment: I showed it for $[[n,1,3]]$ CSS codes. I doubt the same bound holds for non-CSS $$[n,1,3]]$ stabilizer codes. But I don't even know how to start investigating that question. There is too much freedom in non-CSS codes.

Comment: +1 that's an interesting fact about CSS codes. I'm interested more generally in stabilizer codes and especially in specific examples of stabilizer codes with small support. So I think I'll wait and see if other answers address those aspects of the question

Comment: It seems that there is a $ [[9,1,3]] $ CSS code, some version of the Shor code, with code words $ |0>_L=|000 000 000>+ |110 110 110>+ |011 011 011>+ |101 101 101> $ and $ |1>_L=|111 111 111>+ |001 001 001>+ |100 100 100>+ |010 010 010> $, stabilizer generators $ XXI XXI XXI, IXX IXX IXX, ZII ZII III, IZI IZI III, IIZ IIZ III, ZII III ZII, IZI III IZI, IIZ III IIZ  $ . This $ [[n,1,3]] $ CSS code has support less than $ n+1=10 $. So it seems that your answer is wrong. (sorry to be harsh I know you're new!) Is there something here I'm not understanding correctly?

Comment: You are correct. I failed to account for degenerate code, where different phase-flip errors act on encoded states in the same way. This makes the second result only valid for non-degenerate codes.